# How can I devote all the cores to Mathematica?

Tags: parallelization, xact

I have a problem with the calculations speeds in xAct package. In fact, some of them take lots of seconds. Is there any way to speed up the calculations by engaging all the cores for Mathematica (or maybe another way? My laptop is Asus core i7.

Comment: Well, there is [`Parallelize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html), but I personally don't trust it or find it tremendously effective. Generally, for code to be efficiently run in parallel it requires the programmer to put in effort to make it parallelizable. There isn't just a switch you can flip.

Comment: Also, your Mathematica license specifies the maximum number of kernels that can be used.

Comment: @user6014, your comment about not trusting Parallelize worries me since I use it.  May I know why you don't trust it or find it tremendously effective?  I'm not challenging but trying to learn in case my reliance on it is misplaced.